# How to fill a textfield in later frames from the first frame?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dynamic, textfield, htmltext

I have a case where I can change the contents of an actionscript class which fills the dynamic text fields in a flash movie. The class function is called from the first frame in the movie and fills all visible fields. I need to fill a dynamic text field in the n-th frame (say 100, or so) but when I call

```
tagline2.htmlText = "hello there";
```

from the class, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Kan geen eigenschap of methode benaderen via een verwijzing naar een object dat null is.
```

which means as much as

```
Can't reference an attribute or method of an object that's null
```

Any ideas on how I can get text into Dynamic Textfields in later frames then the function call?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the timeline, you could place your dynamic text on it's own layer (assuming it's not), begin the layer on the same frame number as the method, but only make the textfield visible until the 100th frame.

or you could change the linkage of your dynamic text field, exporting it for actionscript and exporting to frame 1.

Comment: I can't change the linkage because of the use of AS3. which disables Dynamic Text Fields from being linkable apparently... Used the first option though!